# Parsing URL for Specific Part of Path

Tags: sql, database, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parse-url

How would I go about extracting a specific part of the path using `PARSE_URL`? For example, if I query...

```
> WITH cte AS (   
> SELECT CONCAT('http://', COLUMN1) AS URL   FROM VALUES
>      ('www.url1.com/test'), 
>      ('www.url1.com/test2/'), 
>      ('www.url1.com/test/sub_test/') ) 
> SELECT URL, 
>        PARSE_URL(URL) AS parts,
>        PARSE_URL(URL):path::text AS path,
>        TRIM(PARSE_URL(URL):path::text, '/') AS path
> FROM cte;
```

For `www.url1.com/test/sub_test`, the `path` is `test/sub_test`, but how would I extract just `sub_test`?

Comment: https://joshdevlin.com/blog/parse-url-snowflake/ might be useful, `parse_url(url):path::varchar` then locate the second `/`. don't think `parse_url` can be used to return part path

Comment: Try this - split_part(TRIM(PARSE_URL(URL):path::text, '/'),'/',-1)

Answer (score -5):

Use `SELECT RIGHT` for it, man. Just you have to find last "/" position